# Creating explicit functions in protractor typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to create a base class to add the explicit weights in click and select methods. This is the code I have tried so far but I am getting the error on Click.on():

```
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { by } from "protractor";
import { protractor, browser } from 'protractor';

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;


export class wait{
    constructor() {
    }

    ElementVisibility(selector){
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath(selector));
    });
    }

    Click(selector) {
    this.ElementVisibility(selector).Click.on()
    }

}
```

Also when I import to another page is this the right way to do it? Sorry i am new to typescript and it is giving error and not recognizing the Click method

```
import { Task, step, PerformsTasks } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay";
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { CheckoutPageMap } from "../interactions/element-mappings/CheckoutPageMap";
import { wait } from "../interactions/element-mappings/wait";

export class FillPaymentMethod implements Task {
  static called(): FillPaymentMethod {
    return new FillPaymentMethod();
  }
  @step('{0} Select Shipping Method - Bruno selects for an item in men section')
  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
      Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.radioCreditCard),
      Enter.theValue('Bruno Sacco').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardHolderName),
      Enter.theValue('4032039926075500').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardNumber),
      Enter.theValue('123').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardCvv),
      wait.Click('//*[@id="card_month"]/option[.=" 09"]'),
      //Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.dropDownCreditCardMonth), // TO-DO: optimize choosing option from dropdown from properties file
      Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.dropDownCreditCardYear) // TO-DO: optimize choosing option from dropdown from properties file
    );
  }
};
```

getting this error - [ts] Property 'Click' does not exist on type 'typeof wait'.

Comment: `Click` is not static but instance method, it requires `new wait()` instance. `wait.Click` would serve no purpose because there's nothing to wait. At this point the class doesn't make sense because it doesn't have state, just serves as namespace for several methods. There's a  problem with `.Click.on()`, `ElementVisibility` doesn't return anything that would have `Click` method. I'm not sure how the class is supposed to work, so I have no ideas how it can be improved to become workable.

Comment: yeah I don't know why I do not use my python basics in this one and always forget they all have the same basics thanks a lot